# Gauss on philosophers

Tags: biographical-details, philosophy-of-science, quote, gauss

Carl Friedrich Gauss said:

> When a philosopher says something that is true then it is trivial. When he says something that is not trivial then it is false.

On one occasion I read that supposedly Gauss has added in parentheses that Aristotle was an exception. Do you know more about it?

If any, I'd be sure that Gauss rather said that "*especially Aristotle*", i.e. that "*Aristotle was **except**ionally bad*".

Thus,

***QUESTION***   what Gauss really said?

Answer (score 10):

The quote is not accurate but Gauss actually wrote something similar to Schumacher in the letter of 1 November 1844 cited [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=rykSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=gauss%20Schumacher%20letter%201%20November%201844&source=bl&ots=3hjc9HrHYD&sig=ACfU3U1v-V1gIWLTHg-2qwJXKSJ9mcLSZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy9pjp99_mAhUI56QKHVPGC8cQ6AEwAnoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=gauss%20Schumacher%20letter%201%20November%201844&f=false), where he complains about concepts and definitions given in math books by philosopher that are not mathematicians, namely

> [...] look around at modern philosophers [...] don't their definitions make your hair stand on end? Read in the history of ancient philosophy what the men of the days, Plato and others (I except Aristotle), gave as explanation.
>   And even in Kant matters are often not much better; his distinction between analytic and synthetic propositions seems to me either a triviality or false.

So Gauss considers Aristotle to be the exception between ancient (and modern) philosophers in the sense that his definitions are free of confusion.

Comment: It is indeed surprising that Gauss seems to be putting Atistotle above Plato for clarity of definitions. Modern historians would disagree: they consider Plato's contribution to  mathematics  very important, unlike that of Aristotle.

Comment: Gauss is citing here Hegel (author of the *Science of Logic*), Schelling (who criticized Hegel's view about logic), Wolff and Kant (both authors of a *Logic*), Nees von Esenbeck (botanist, but also author of *System der spekulativen Philosophie*), and Plato (no logical treatise have survived, but he dealt with truth and falseness in *Theaetetus* and with the nature of definitions in many dialogues, like *Euthyphro*), so **my personal opinion** is that here Gauss is appreciating Aristotle as the author of the *Organon*, which is actually a pretty clear logic textbook.

Comment: Thank you U6530, +1, and let me wait for eventual later answers. I see that Aristotle was appreciated by Gauss for just one item, for its logical narration. I would also like to know about any Plato's ***original*** contribution to mathematics, was there any? Any at all?

Comment: @WlodAA be aware of the fact that Gauss' appreciation of Organon is only a personal deduction. On the other hand it's well known that Gauss' view on infinity is close to that of Aristotle: both refuse *actual* infinity in mathematcs, whose demonstrative needs are well served (in their view) by *potential* infinity. About Plato, this can be the subject for another question, but remember that Plato was not a mathematician.

Comment: Rejection of *actual infinity* was an old Greek **mathematician's** tradition. Aristotle was only repeating it long after mathematicians. Indeed, neither Plato nor Aristotle was a mathematician however they were political and PR artists who for millennia get credit for mathematicians' views and discoveries.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the rejection of actual infinity in Greek tradition. In Aristotle's Physics, Book III, we found: *some as the Pythagoreans and Plato make the infinite a principle in the sense of a self-subsistent substance, and not as a mere attribute of some other thing. Only the Pythagoreans place the infinite among the objects of sense[...], Plato [...] that the infinite is present not only in the objects of sense but in the Forms also. [...] Anaxagora and Democritus [...] that the infinite is continuous by contact*